# List value doesn't update after append

Tags: python, list

Here is my original code:

```
friends_2017 = ["Robert","John","Smith"]
friends_2018 = ["Andy","David","Tim"]
new_friends = []
all_friends = friends_2017 + friends_2018 + new_friends
print(str(all_friends))
ask_friend = input("Who are you looking for")
if ask_friend in friends_2017:
    print(ask_friend,"is in 2017 friends list")
elif ask_friend in friends_2018:
    print(ask_friend,"is in 2018 friends list")
else:
    print("You don't have this friend")
add_friends = input("Who do you want to add?")
year = input("What year do you want to add them in?")
if year == "2017":
    friends_2017.append(add_friends)
elif year == "2018":
    friends_2018.append(add_friends)
else:
    new_friends.append(add_friends)
print(all_friends)
```

I am trying to ask user input for the and the name of the friend, if it matches 2017 or 2018 list, then it when output the year, else it will create new list.

```
if year == "2017":
    friends_2017.append(add_friends)
elif year == "2018":
    friends_2018.append(add_friends)
else:
    new_friends.append(add_friends)
print(all_friends)
```

This last part, it supposed to update the orignal list after all the condition, however it doesn't print out the new list with the new names after all the condition pass. 
May I ask where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
all_friends = friends_2017 + friends_2018 + new_friends
```

creates a new list that contains a copy of everything in the other three lists at that point in time -- it's not a reference to the other three lists, so when you make changes to the original three lists, those changes don't apply to `all_friends`.

The reason that `all_friends` is a new list in this instance is that the `+` operator creates a new list out of its operands.  If you just set `all_friends = new_friends` then `all_friends` would just be a reference to the existing `new_friends` list, and anything you did to one would affect the other.

---

The way I would recommend keeping `all_friends` up to date would be to make it a function that computes the list on demand, rather than its own list:

```
friends_2017 = ["Robert","John","Smith"]
friends_2018 = ["Andy","David","Tim"]
new_friends = []
def all_friends():
    return friends_2017 + friends_2018 + new_friends
print(str(all_friends()))
```

Now any time you access `all_friends()` (note the parentheses, because now it's a function call), it will always have the latest values from those three lists.

Another option would be to regenerate `all_friends` every time you append to the other lists:

```
if year == "2017":
    friends_2017.append(add_friends)
elif year == "2018":
    friends_2018.append(add_friends)
else:
    new_friends.append(add_friends)
all_friends = friends_2017 + friends_2018 + new_friends
```

but this requires you to remember to do this every time any of those lists is modified.  If you go with the method of using a function, it will just magically work every time.

Comment: so I assume if I set ``` all friends = new_friends = friends_2017 = friends_2018 ``` that 3 lines will solve the problem?
Thank you btw

Comment: I'll update this answer with a couple of suggestions on how you might be able to keep `all_friends` up to date.

Answer (score 1):

`+` creates a *new* list from the contents of its operands. There is no relationship between the value of `all_friends` and the future values of `friends_2017` et al. If you want `all_friends` to be up to date, set it after updating the appropriate year list.

Comment: `all_friends = []
all_friends.append(friends_2018)
all_friends.append(friends_2017)
all_friends.append(new_friends)`
I manage to fixed and get the code to work, however the output when I print(all_friends) is not as beauty, 
`[['Andy', 'David', 'Tim'], ['Robert', 'John', 'Smith', 'Will'], []]`
Is there a way I can make it nicer?

Comment: That's because `all_friends` is now a list of references to other lists, not a list of values in the other lists.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at an even simpler example:

```
friends_2017 = ["Robert","John","Smith"]
friends_2018 = ["Andy","David","Tim"]
new_friends = []
all_friends = friends_2017 + friends_2018 + new_friends
add_friends = input("Who do you want to add?")
friends_2017.append(add_friends)
print(friends_2017)
print(all_friends)
```

`all_friends` is a new list that is created by concatenating 3 lists together. Then you append to one of those lists. This won't change `all_friends` because it is an entirely separate list.